# error printing array when looping over it

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for the relatively newbie question. 
Ive been stuck the past hour trying to figure out why the array named $propname does not want to print when i loop over it. Here follows my code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `player_info` WHERE `position` = 'THP'") or die(mysql_error()) ;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //create arrays
{   
    $id[] = $row['player_id'];      
    $propName[] = $row['name'];
    $propLastName[]= $row['surname'];
}//end while

 //create variables for looping
$x = sizeof($propName);
$index = 0;

while($index < $x) //print variables
{
    echo $propName[$index];
    $index ++;
}
```

Comment: you aren't `echo`ing.

Comment: A tip as you work with PHP: It is really uncommon in PHP to use a construct like your `while($index < $x)` to loop an array. Much more common is to `foreach ($propName as $p) { echo $p; }` There is no need to store each of the `player_id, name, surname` into _separate_ arrays. Create _one_ multidimensional array: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $results[] = $row; }`

Comment: sorry i forgot to put echo in when I was writing over my code. If I put echo in it still does not print :(

Comment: Finally, since you are learning, _DO NOT LEARN_ with `mysql_query()`. That extension is deprecated. If you're working from a tutorial, put it down and find a more up to date one, which teaches proper use of PDO or MySQLi via parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify your code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `player_info` WHERE `position` = 'THP'") or die(mysql_error()) ;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //create arrays
{   
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. im just very curious why the above example did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `player_info` WHERE `position` = 'THP'") or             die(mysql_error()) ;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) //create arrays
{   
    $id = $row['player_id'];      
    echo $propName = $row['name'];
    $propLastName = $row['surname'];
}
```